# how to show alphabetical letters in right side of screen

Tags: android

i just want to show alphabetical letters on right side of my screen and my screen contain list of all names in phone contacts this feature is already given in android phone when we open phone contacts then in right side one vertical list appear that show all alphabetical letter and when i click it show that contacts start with that letter so i just want to implement this feature in my app. and i have also tried this one

```
 <List View
   android:fastscrollenabled="true"
    />
so i don't need this scroll so please suggest me the solution.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey raju this is not i want u show me the link to show header in my list but i want to show alphabets list in right side of screen . this feature is in samsung galaxy y and now days set when we open phone contacts then in right side it show vertical list of alphabets...

Answer (score 0):

See [AkphabeticalIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html) for the same, also you can use following link:

http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/